# my turtle screen closes as soon as it opens

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I am making a game through tkinter and turtle graphics. My 2 player mode works perfectly however in single mode, the screen shuts down as soon as it opens. I tried exitonclick method but using this my turtle doesn't move.Another problem I face is that I want a label inside a picture to show winner so how can I do it.

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import *
#Single Player
def single():
    Name_1 = inputname.get().strip()
    opl.destroy()
    windows = Screen()
    windows.title("Bounce Game by TechLord")
    windows.bgcolor("white")
    windows.setup(width=1200, height=760)
    windows.tracer(0)

# Score
score = 0

# paddle a
paddle = Turtle()
paddle.speed(0)
paddle.shape("square")
paddle.color("blue")
paddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=5)
paddle.penup()
paddle.goto(0, -330)


# ball
ball = Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("red")
ball.shapesize(stretch_wid=1.2, stretch_len=1.2)
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 1
ball.dy = 1

# Pen
pen = Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("black")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 330)
pen.write("{}: 0".format(Name_1), align="center", font=("Bebas Neue", 24, "italic"))

# Function
def paddle_right():
    x = paddle.xcor()
    x += 20
    paddle.setx(x)

def paddle_left():
    x = paddle.xcor()
    x -= 20
    paddle.setx(x)


# keyboard binding
windows.listen()
windows.onkeypress(paddle_right, "Right")
windows.onkeypress(paddle_left, "Left")


# Main loop
while score < 10:
    windows.update()
    # moving ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # border checking

    # Top and Side borders
    if ball.ycor() > 380:
        ball.sety(380)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 600:
        ball.setx(600)
        ball.dx *= -1


    if ball.xcor() < -600:
        ball.setx(-600)
        ball.dx *= -1

    # paddle and ball collisions
    if ball.ycor() < -320 and ball.ycor() > -330 and (ball.xcor() < paddle.xcor() + 55 and ball.xcor() > paddle.xcor() - 55):
        ball.setx(-330)
        ball.dx *= -1
    else:
        score += 1
Screen().bye()

#Double Player
def double():
    name_1 = inputname1.get().strip()
    name_2 = inputname2.get().strip()
    pl.destroy()
    windows = Screen()
    windows.title("Bounce Game by TechLord")
    windows.bgcolor("white")
    windows.setup(width=1200, height=760)
    windows.tracer(0)

# Score
score_a = 0
score_b = 0

# paddle a
pad_a = Turtle()
pad_a.speed(0)
pad_a.shape("square")
pad_a.color("blue")
pad_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
pad_a.penup()
pad_a.goto(-550, 0)

# paddle b
pad_b = Turtle()
pad_b.speed(0)
pad_b.shape("square")
pad_b.color("blue")
pad_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
pad_b.penup()
pad_b.goto(550, 0)

# ball
ball = Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("red")
ball.shapesize(stretch_wid=1.2, stretch_len=1.2)
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 1
ball.dy = -1

# Pen
pen = Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("black")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 330)
pen.write("{}: 0  {}: 0".format(name_1, name_2), align="center", font=("Bebas Neue", 24, "italic"))

# Function
def pad_a_up():
    y = pad_a.ycor()
    y += 20
    pad_a.sety(y)

def pad_a_down():
    y = pad_a.ycor()
    y -= 20
    pad_a.sety(y)

def pad_b_up():
    y = pad_b.ycor()
    y += 20
    pad_b.sety(y)

def pad_b_down():
    y = pad_b.ycor()
    y -= 20
    pad_b.sety(y)

# keyboard binding
windows.listen()
windows.onkeypress(pad_a_up, "w")
windows.onkeypress(pad_a_down, "s")
windows.onkeypress(pad_b_up, "Up")
windows.onkeypress(pad_b_down, "Down")

# Main loop
while score_a < 10 and score_b < 10:
    windows.update()
    # moving ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # border checking

    # Top and Bottom
    if ball.ycor() > 370:
        ball.sety(370)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.ycor() < -370:
        ball.sety(-370)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 610:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_a += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("{}: {}  {}: {}".format(name_1, score_a, name_2, score_b), align="center",
                  font=("Bebas Neue", 24, "italic"))

    if ball.xcor() < -610:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_b += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("{}: {}  {}: {}".format(name_1, score_a, name_2, score_b), align="center",
                  font=("Bebas Neue", 24, "italic"))

    # paddle and ball collisions
    if ball.xcor() > 540 and ball.xcor() < 550 and (
            ball.ycor() < pad_b.ycor() + 55 and ball.ycor() > pad_b.ycor() - 55):
        ball.setx(540)
        ball.dx *= -1
    if ball.xcor() < -540 and ball.xcor() > -550 and (
            ball.ycor() < pad_a.ycor() + 55 and ball.ycor() > pad_a.ycor() - 55):
        ball.setx(-540)
        ball.dx *= -1
if score_a == 10:
    res = Tk()
    pic = PhotoImage(file=r"F:\hassan\winner.png")
    picture = Label(res, image=pic).grid(row=0, column=0)
    winner = Label(res, In=picture, text=name_1, justify=CENTER).pack(side=BOTTOM)
elif score_b == 10:
    res = Tk()
    pic = PhotoImage(file=r"F:\hassan\winner.png")
    picture = Label(res, image=pic).grid(row=0, column=0)
    winner = Label(res, In=picture, text=name_2, justify=CENTER).pack(side=BOTTOM)
Screen().bye()

def twoplayer():
    global inputname1
    global inputname2
    global pl
    win.destroy()
    pl = Tk()
    pl.title("Name Entry")
    inputname1 = StringVar()
    inputname2 = StringVar()
    pl1 = Label(pl, text="Player 1", fg="black", font=("arial", 20), justify=LEFT).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    pl2 = Label(pl, text="Player 2", fg="black", font=("arial", 20), justify=LEFT).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    name1 = Entry(pl, width=20, font=("bebas neue", 20, "italic"), bg="white", textvariable=inputname1, justify=LEFT)
    name1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
    name2 = Entry(pl, width=20, font=("bebas neue", 20, "italic"), bg="white", textvariable=inputname2, justify=LEFT)
    name2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
    start = Button(pl, text="start", fg="white", bg="black", bd=3, font=("bebas neue", 20), cursor="hand2", width=8, height=1, command=double).grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    pl.mainloop()

def oneplayer():
    global inputname
    global opl
    win.destroy()
    opl = Tk()
    opl.title("Name Entry")
    inputname = StringVar()
    pl1 = Label(opl, text="Player 1", fg="black", font=("arial", 20), justify=LEFT).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    name1 = Entry(opl, width=20, font=("bebas neue", 20, "italic"), bg="white", textvariable=inputname, justify=LEFT)
    name1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
    start = Button(opl, text="start", fg="white", bg="black", bd=3, font=("bebas neue", 20), cursor="hand2", width=8, height=1, command=single).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    opl.mainloop()

#Defining game start menu
win = Tk()
win.title("Start Menu")
win.geometry("350x500")
img = PhotoImage(file=r"F:\hassan\First year\Programming Fundamentals(PL)\bounce.png")
image = Label(win, image=img).grid(row=0, column=0)
name = Label(win, text="BOUNCE!!", fg="red", font=("arial black", 30, "italic")).grid()
byline = Label(win, text="By TechLord", fg="brown", font=("arial black", 10, "italic")).grid()
one_player = Button(win, text="1 Player", fg="black", bg="blue", font=("calibri", 20, "bold"), cursor="hand2", command=oneplayer).grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10)
two_player = Button(win, text="2 Player", fg="black", bg="turquoise", font=("calibri", 20, "bold"), cursor="hand2", command=twoplayer).grid(row=4, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that variables used in loops and conditional statements are what you're assuming they are? Have you verified that functions you assume are being called are actually being called?

Comment: well i tried by adding print statements to check if they reach there or not. Well they do reach there.

Comment: I see `Name_1` and `windows` are not defined. It appears they are defined in a function and not global where they are being called multiple times. These errors should be showing up on your end. You are also using a while loop in the same thread as Tkinter. This will cause problems.

Comment: I can also see that you are using more than one instance of `Tk()`. This is not how tkinter is used. You only ever want to have 1 instance of `Tk()` and for each new window you will use `Toplevel()`. That said I think your program is going to need a lot of editing to make it work. You have a mix of things that don't work together.

Comment: So can you please help a bit. Tell me what to change

Comment: Then why does it work for 2 player and not 1 player?